# How do I print numbers from 1 to n in python in a single line without spaces?

Tags: python, numbers

```py
print(*range(1, int(input())+1), sep='')
```

This was the code I found in a discussion on hacker rank. But I did not understand it.
Can anyone please explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from what I can tell, this is how it works:

```py
int(input())
```

This takes input from the user.
Next;

```py
range(1,...+1)
```

This creates a range from 1 to our number we inputted earlier. The +1 means that it will include the max number.
And then:

```py
print(*...,sep='')
```

The `*` sign, from what I can tell, just effectively returns each value in our range one to be printed.
The `sep=''` just means each value is separated by `''` or nothing.

Hope this is useful to you.

[EDIT]

More on star and double star expressions in this post:
[What does the star and doublestar operator mean in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-and-doublestar-operator-mean-in-a-function-call)

Comment: The `*` performs unpacking, each element will be a parameter of `print`

Comment: @mozway thanks, I didn't know that before.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so we have `print` function. Inside we have this strange `*range(1, int(input())+1)` this is range function which return value from 1 to n (n is typed in `input`) in a form of a range object. `*` unpack this object to form like: `1 2 3 4 ...` with spaces, so we have this sep='', keyword argument that makes separation from space to '' (no separate between).
Also you can do it like that:

```
n = input("Type integer value: ")
try:
    [print(x+1,end="") for x in range(int(n))]
except ValueError:
    exit("Typed string not number")
```

Comment: (Mis)using a list comprehension just to invoke a side effect isn't the best of ideas. It confuses future readers.